# How to find inverse of $y = x C_1 + \tan^{-1}(x + rh) + C_2$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

I have a function as below for which inputs are x, and rh. $C_i$ are constants.

$$
y = x C_1 + \tan^{-1}(x + rh) + C_2  \tag{1}
$$

Now, given y, I need to find x. I could not find any relation in arctan that could help me here. Kindly help.

**Background**: I am trying to reverse the [stull's formula](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/JAMC-D-11-0143.1) to find dry bulb temperature, given wet bulb temperature and relative humidity. Eq(1) is simplified form of stull's formula.

If I take $u = y - C_2, v = x, D = rh$ then I get, via tangent simplification,

$$
u = \dfrac{v(1+C_1) + D}{1 - vC_1(v - D)}  \tag{2}
$$

where I am still lost, because I need to find $v$ for given $u$, but (2) is other way round.

Comment: If I may suggest : forget it and consider numerical methods.

Comment: kindly suggest numerical methods that could best suit in these situations?

Comment: Newton method would be simple **provided** a reasonable estimate. Otherwise, just bisection.

Comment: I checked that, but could not understand where and how to start. The logic for this has to go in to PLC, so any simpler method available?

Comment: If $(2)$ is valid, it is a quadratic equation in $v$

Answer (score 1):

Since, from comments, you seem to be concerned by a rather narrow range for $T$, what you could do is to expand the rhs of the equation
$$y = C_1 T + \tan^{-1}(T + rh) + C_2$$ as a Taylor series at the midpoint (say at $T=T_{mid}$).

This would give
$$y=\left(C_1T_{mid} +\tan ^{-1}(T_{mid}+rh)+C_2\right)+(T-T_{mid})
   \left(\frac{1}{(T_{mid}+rh)^2+1}+C_1\right)+O\left((T-T_{mid})^2\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are known:

We have $y-xC_1-C_2=\arctan(x+rh)$. Now using the fact that $\tan(\arctan x) = x$ for all real $x$, we can simplify to reach a form where we can apply a Taylor approximation:

Since you are given $y$ and $C_2$, you only have something in the form $\tan(xa+b)$. Using the fact that $\tan(-x) = -\tan(x)$ and the addition formula for tangent:

$$x = \tan(y-xC_1 - C_2) +rh$$
$$= -\tan(-y+xC_1+C_2) + rh$$
$$= -\tan\big((-y+C_2) + xC_1 \big) + rh$$

and now you can use the Taylor series approximation given by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(a%2Bb)+taylor+series):

$$x \approx \tan b + rh + a \sec^2 b + a^2 \tan b \sec^2 b + O(a^3)$$

Comment: $x$ is temperature so would be real (between 20 to 40 deg realistically). In your method, I would get, $tan(y  - xC_1 - C_2) = x + rh$ I believe? It still results in another complicated form as [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-tan-a-b-c-tana-tanb-tanc-tanatanbtanc-1-tanatanb-tanbtanc-tanct) with $x$ and $y$ binded together?

Comment: and yes, $C_1, C_2, rh$ are known